# How to use GROUP_CONCAT in a CONCAT in MySql AND SUM VALUES

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, concatenation, group-concat

I have a table with the following data in MySQL.

```
Id Name Total 
1   A    25
2   B    10
1   C    5
1   D    10
2   F    7
```

how do I get it into the following format?

```
id   column   total
1     A,C,D     40
2     B,F       17
```

Comment: Why do you want this? :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use group_concat on one column and sum on the other.

```
select id, 
    group_concat(name order by name) as names,
    sum(total) as total
from your_table
group by id;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/VIPNE29581)

Comment: Thank you so much.